# jQuery filter empty values and join non-empty values with comma delimiter

Tags: jquery, regex, concatenation

I have the following form. When an address input field is changed I want to format the longaddress field which is a comma delimited concatenated string of each address field. I want to remove any empty fields from the string and sanitize the city and country fields. Currently I do it as follows:

```
 <input id="address1" type="text" value="" name="address1" >
 <input id="address2" type="text" value="" name="address2" >
 <input id="city" type="text" value="" name="city" >
 <input id="postcode" type="text" value="" name="postcode" >
 <input id="country" type="text" value="" name="country" >

 <input id="longaddress" type="text" value="" name="longaddress" >


<script>
  $("#address1, #address2, #city, #country, #postcode").on('change', function (e) {

    var generatedAddress = '';

    if ($('#address1').val().length > 0)
        generatedAddress +=  $('#address1').val().trim();

    if ($('#address2').val().length > 0)
        generatedAddress +=  ', ' + $('#address2').val().trim(); 

    var city = $('#city').val();
    if (city.replace(/[\s,.]+$/, '').length > 0)
        generatedAddress +=  ', ' + city; 

    if ($('#postcode').val().length > 0)
        generatedAddress +=  ', ' + $('#postcode').val().trim(); 


    var country = $('#country').val();
    if (country.replace(/[\s,.]+$/, '').length > 0)
        generatedAddress +=  ', ' + country;

     $("#longaddress).val(generatedAddress);
  });

 </script>
```

Is there a more elegant way to achieve the same?

Comment: @Tushar how do i include the regex for city and country?

Comment: @tushar the above only gives me `[object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLInputElement], [object HTMLInputElement]`. My implementation as follows: `var longaddress = $("#Address1, #Address2, #City, #Country, #Postcode").filter(function () {
            return this.value.trim();
        }).get().join(', ');

       
        console.log(longaddress);`